# Ideal stubs utility for php unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, stub, utilities

I am looking utility for the stubs for unit testing in php.
Stub must meet typehinting. Must be able to check the method calls with parameters. Must be able to return values ​​according to the specified parameters.
Do you know any?

Answer (score 1):

[Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) is a great option:

From GitHub [padraic / mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery)

> Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework for use in
>   unit testing with PHPUnit, PHPSpec or any other testing framework. Its
>   core goal is to offer a test double framework with a succint API
>   capable of clearly defining all possible object operations and
>   interactions using a human readable Domain Specific Language (DSL).
>   Designed as a drop in alternative to PHPUnit's phpunit-mock-objects
>   library, Mockery is easy to integrate with PHPUnit and can operate
>   alongside phpunit-mock-objects without the World ending.
>
> Mockery is released under a New BSD License.